# Insert product Magento 2 via REST

Tags: magento2

How to add a product to Magento 2 via REST api. 
Do I need some kind of authentication and if so how can I achieve that?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can set simple product from below script,

```
$url="http://127.0.0.1/magento2.1/";  //set your magento front url
$token_url=$url."rest/V1/integration/admin/token";
$product_url=$url. "rest/V1/products";
$username="admin";  //admin username
$password="admin123"; //admin password
//Authentication rest API magento2, get access token
$ch = curl_init();
$data = array("username" => $username, "password" => $password);
$data_string = json_encode($data);

$ch = curl_init($token_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))
    );
$token = curl_exec($ch);
$adminToken=  json_decode($token);

$sampleProductData = array(
        'sku'               => 'test123',
        'name'              => 'Test 123',
        'visibility'        => 4, 
        'type_id'           => 'simple',
        'price'             => 100,
        'status'            => 1,
        'attribute_set_id'  => 4,
        'weight'            => 1,
        'custom_attributes' => array(
            array( 'attribute_code' => 'category_ids', 'value' => ["4","5"] ),
            array( 'attribute_code' => 'description', 'value' => 'description' ),
            array( 'attribute_code' => 'short_description', 'value' => 'Simple Short Description' )            
        ),
        'extension_attributes' => array(
                "stock_item"=>array(
                        "qty"=>1000,
                        "is_in_stock"=>true,
                ),                    
        )
    );
$productData = json_encode(array('product' => $sampleProductData));

$setHaders = array('Content-Type:application/json','Authorization:Bearer '.$adminToken);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $product_url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $productData);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $setHaders);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```